# Итерация по папке текстовых файлов Python. Метод __getitem__

Tags: python

При итерации происходит обращение к **getitem**, который я переопределила.Вопрос, что должен возвращать метод по окончанию элементов? При возврате False или None итерация продолжается как ни в чем не бывало.

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if index > len(self):
        return False  # Вот здесь должен быть выход. А его нет.(
    new_text = ''
    working_file = self.path_in + '/' + self.files[index-1]
    with open(working_file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            new_line = ''
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.lower()
                new_word = ''
                for symbol in word:
                    if symbol not in ',.<>/-|!@#$%^&*()+=:;':
                        new_word += symbol
                new_line += new_word + ' '
            new_text += new_line
    return new_text
```

Comment: При обращении к несуществующему индексу принято выбрасывать исключение IndexError

Comment: куда вставить IndexError?
Если в первый return, то продолжает итерироваться